# How can i find if my string contains nine digits?

Tags: perl

how can i find if string contains 9 digits?
this is the cokde that I tried.

```
if($string ~= m/\d{9}/){
    print ("String contains 9 digits");
}
```

thanx.

Comment: Change `~=` to `=~`.  However, saying so would simply match if the string _contains_ 9 digits; it doesn't ensure that the string contains _only_ 9 digits.

Comment: how can i ensure that string only contains 9 digits? (how can i get rid of any whitespaces)

Comment: Add anchors: say `$string =~ m/^\d{9}$/`

Comment: Are digits consecutive or not?

Comment: they are consecutive and i want to also match nine digits that are preceeded or followed by whitespaces e.g ' 123456798 '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `~=` to `=~`

```
if($string =~ m/\d{9}/){
    print ("String contains 9 digits");
}
```

This will match any string containing *at-least* 9 didts

---

> how can i ensure that string only contains 9 digits?

Try enclosing match within `^` and `$`

```
if($string =~ m/^\d{9}$/){
    print ("String only contains 9 digits");
}
```

---

> i want to also match nine digits that are preceeded or followed by
>   whitespaces e.g ' 123456798 '

Try specifying `\s*` at the beginning and end of the string

```
if($string =~ m/^\s*\d{9}\s*$/){
    print ("String contains only 9 digits with optional leading or trailing spaces");
}
```

**P.S.** Observe the difference in the meaning of print message in all the cases. They are not same!

Comment: i want to also match nine digits that are preceeded or followed by whitespaces e.g  '  123456798 '

Comment: the problem with using word boundries is that m/\b\d{9}\b/ returns true for the following string 'a 123456789  g ' in such a case

Comment: Then try (a) to specify your requirements more carefully up front, and (b) `/^\s*\d{9}\s*$/`.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your comment. I was updating the answer with same regex.

Comment: @tripleee thanx man, sorry for the lack of specification up front -